# How can i use :after in CSS onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function mutevideo(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains('fa-video-camera')) {
    evt.target.classList.remove('fa-video-camera')
    evt.target.classList.add('fa-video-camera:after') // need here above fontawesom class with slash
  } else {
    evt.target.classList.remove('fa-video-camera:after') // need here above fontawesom class with slash
    evt.target.classList.add('fa-video-camera')
  }
}
```

```css
.fa-video-camera:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "/";
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p class="bg-white text-danger rounded-circle"><i onClick=mutevideo(evt) class="fa fa-video-camera p-2 fa-1x"></i></p>
```

**Problem**:-

In fontawesome 4.7 version it don't have slash video as it have in version of 5.x, so here i wrote my own css with `:after` to make this achieve, Now how where i will get video slash as soon as page loads, but my requirement is i need slash on icon after i click.

**Note**:-

here i'm using fontawesome version 4.7, any help or suggestion are heartily thank you

Comment: You can NOT access `:after` like this in JS as its not part of the DOM so it will not able accessible.

Comment: hi @AlwaysHelping, thank you for your suggestion, can you please show me how can i achieve this.

Comment: @unique What are trying to achieve?

Comment: `:after` (or `::after`) in CSS refers to [adding content after an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after); it's not part of the class name, and has nothing to do with "after it's been clicked".

Comment: Also note that although you say "the above code works fine", clicking "Run Snippet" actually results in an error. Please [edit] to make sure you have a [mcve], along with a clear explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: hi @ibrahimmahrir please check my updated question.

Comment: hi @IMSoP i have updated my snippet please try now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a custom class `.stop` to add a slash in your font-awesome icon on click. There is no need to add another icon to add a slash.

To show and hide on click we can simply use [toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) function instead of doing alot of `if's` and `else` or `add` or `remove` classes

Run snippet below.

```js
function mutevideo(evt) {
  if (evt.classList.contains('fa-video-camera')) {
    evt.classList.toggle('stop')
  }
}
```

```css
.stop:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "/";
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 23px;
  left: 11px;
  top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p class="bg-white rounded-circle"><i onClick=mutevideo(this) class="fa fa-video-camera p-2 fa-1x"></i></p>
```

Comment: thank you @alwayshelping, this saved my day, i was trying this from past 5 hrs.